# Removing pattern at the end of a string using sed or other bash tools

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I would like to remove any ABC at the end of the string.

The best I have came up with is

```
echo ${String}| sed -e 's/["ABC"]*$//g'
```

However, it will remove all the A, or B or C at the end of the string.

If String is DAAAAABCBBBCCABCABC, if I use the above expression, it will return "D", instead of "DAAAAABCBBBCC"

Is there any better way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo "DAAAAABCBBBCCABCABC" | sed -e 's/\(ABC\)*$//g'
```

Result:

```
DAAAAABCBBBCC
```

Surround string between parentheses and `*` applies to all letters inside them in that exact order.

Comment: Why `sed -e 's/\(;;\)*$//g'  foo.csv` does not delete `;;` from end of lines? for example, I have a line `County;4;5;0;20;4;5;4;5;;` and the output is the same.

Comment: @Sigur: It works for me. Check that there aren't any blanks at the end.

Comment: I discovered the problem. It was end of line char. It worked.

Answer (score 32):

bash can do this internally. The following removes any "ABC" string at the end, and its result can used in variable assignment, a command or whatever:

```
${String%ABC}
```

You can also use a regex, not just a simple string match. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: This will only remove the last occurrence of `ABC`. This kind of Shell Parameter Expansion uses glob, so its not possible to express "any number of ABC's" with it. More info: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: @LopSae with extended globs (`shopt -s extglob`), it would work: `${String%%+(ABC)}`

Comment: Is it possible to put regex in there?

Comment: Yes, see the link. I edited the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: That's technically not regex btw, but rather a [bash glob pattern](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/pattern-matching-bash).

Comment: Yes, my example is a pattern match. Then I said that it is also possible to use a regex. I didn't call my example a regex. :-)

Answer (score 6):

You should use:

```
sed -E 's/(ABC)+$//'
```

OR:

```
sed -r 's/(ABC)+$//'
```

Both will give output:

```
DAAAAABCBBBCC
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that both parameters enable interpreting the the expresion as an extended regular expression. I have seen `-E` used by Mac (Darwin) and `-r` by other linux distributions.

Comment: `-E` is an undocumented option for compatibility with BSD sed. You should almost certainly be using `-r`. `-E` will fail on the busybox version of sed.

Comment: Years of using basic sed and I was confused why `sed -e 's/^[0-9]+//'` wasn't working. Usually decade old tech answers are outdated but this one wasn't. thanks!